# Can't restore .Net Core solution with DotNetCoreCLI task on Azure Devops

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to restore a .Net Core project on `Azure DevOps` like this:

```yaml
steps:

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Get solution path'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $solutionPath = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.sln -Recurse | Select-Object -Expand Directory -First 1

      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=solutionPath]$solutionPath"

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Restore'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      dotnet restore
    workingDirectory: "$(solutionPath)"

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Restore'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    workingDirectory: "$(solutionPath)"
```

My first restore task using `PowerShell` works just fine, yet my second one with `DotNetCoreCLI` fails with this error:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in a simpler way

```yaml
#Restore packages with the .NET Core CLI task
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.sln'
```

and if you want to use your way please make sure that you select correct path by listing files before restore

```
- script: ls '$(solutionPath)'
```

Comment: Am I not already selecting the path with my  `workingDirectory: "$(solutionPath)"` directive? I'm even doing it for both tasks.

Comment: I've adopted your solution as it is indeed easier, yet I'm still curious why my initial code does not work.

Comment: I was just curious what is inside that path. Just to be sure, that all is fine. But I'm glad we solved your issue.

Comment: The `.sln` is there, I've confirmed that by running a `dir` on my `Powershell` task.

Comment: You didn't specify there `projects` settings, so I'm not sure what is looking for. You can try add `projects: '*.sln' to your version.